# Эффективный код пути навигации

Tags: php

Добрый день!
Человек перешёл на страницу друзья, потом в онлайн, там выбрал друга, нужно сделать ссылки вида Друзья->Онлайн->Иван Иванов, то есть нужно сформировать обратный путь, писать на каждой странице ссылки, или как сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.
А если сделать так? например в GET - `action=friends&section=online;`

```
$action = array("friends"=>"Друзья","setting"=>"Настройка");
$other = array("section"=>array("online"=>"Онлайн","offline"=>"Оффлайн"));
echo '<a href="?action="{$_GET['action']}">{$action[$_GET['action']]}</a> / <a href="">?action="{$_GET['action']}>{$action[$_GET['section']]}</a>';
```

Comment: **Оффтоп**

Вам самому так удобно будет?

Я, например, читаю код - и уже забываю что где есть.

Про [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) слышали? Полезно будет услышать))

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сформировать обратный путь, можно подключить древовидную структуру сайта.
Оттуда вытягиваем "хлебные крошки" - как раз то, что вы изобразили.

Чем проще дерево и чем меньше зависимостей, тем проще в автоматическом режиме формировать данный элемент навигации.

пример:

```
array(
  'friends'=>array(
    'online',
    'offline'
  ),
  'settings'=>array(
    'security',
    'profile',
  )
);

$_SESSION['path'] .= '/'.$current_page; //$current_page получаем так или иначе из get, например, при использовании mod_rewrite для ЧПУ.
```

Comment: Посмотрите дополнение

Comment: Если в сессии и хранить путь навигации, то точно не строкой, т.к. после FRIENDS-ONLINE-FRIENDS-ONLINE и т.д. вы сами рады не будете.

Если и хранить в сессии, то хранить массив - где были и откуда пришли. И на каждой странице убирать не только петли, но и "невидимые" петли.

Т.е. например получили MAIN - FRIEND - ONLINE, а затем перешли через меню в настройки. Путь должен быть не MAIN - FRIEND - ONLINE - OPTIONS, а MAIN - OPTIONS, т.к. OPTIONS относится к MAIN, а не к ONLINE

Comment: по поводу дополнения: это можно, если путь в строке адреса точно соответствует позициям в крошках.
Приведу пример:

    ?section=catalog&product=255&model=2

Должно отобразиться как  
>Каталог/Пылесосы/Без-Мешка-Для-Сбора-Пыли/ИМЯ_ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЯ/МОДЕЛЬ(255)/ВАРИАЦИЯ(2)

Так что если все как вы описываете, то вам повезло. В противном случае, я уже про это же спрашивал. Примерно тут: http://hashcode.ru/questions/182384/php-произвольное-меню-сайта

вкратце: сайту нужно не менее 4 независимых меню для приемлемой гибкости отображения.